# Zotero-compatible electronics datasheet archive?

Tags: zotero

I am thinking about using [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) to archive my electronic component datasheet collection - mostly datasheets of embedded CPU chipsets. I am less than thrilled, though, at the idea of manually creating the metadata for all those documents.

There are, however, a few on-line stores that allow potential customers to download the datasheet for most of the components on sale.

Is there any such store that is supported by Zotero, either out-of-the-box or with an additional translator?

Alternatively, is there a way to automatically get such information? Using Google Scholar either manually, or via the "Retrieve PDF metadata" command, does not seem to work, probably because datasheets are not exactly academic publications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a supported store or datasheet archive, even after several hours of searching. I finally decided to create my own [Zotero translators](http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/translators) for the sites that I frequent.

I was able to create a (somewhat incomplete) translator for the [Farnell](http://farnell.com/) website in just a few hours, with no past experience of note in JavaScript, XPath or Zotero.

Comment: Did you publish your code anywhere? I don't have a big collection of datasheets but I do find the manual importing a bit annoying...